# How to authorise verticalresponse with Bearer token using curl in wordpress gravity form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, wordpress-rest-api

I am using gravity form with wordpress to integrate Verticalresponse subscription form with curl to authorise with bearer token but unable to establish a connection

```
function post_to_vr($entry, $form ) {
  $raw_data = [
    'email' => $entry
  ];
  $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer x7ab8errzuj87u24qemzytu3"; 

  $ch = curl_init('https://vrapi.verticalresponse.com/api/v1/lists/36283883717887/contacts');

  $data = json_encode($raw_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return json_decode($result);
}
add_action("gform_after_submission", "post_to_vr",10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty ok except only one thing i.e.

**replace:**

```
$raw_data = [
    'email' => $entry
];
```

**with:**

```
$raw_data = [
    'email' => $entry[x]
];
```

where "**x**" will be the index value of array which holds the email data.

Hope this will help. Happy coding.